# Check if a process is a Go application (in Linux/Unix)

Tags: linux, unix, process, go, ps

I am using ps (specifically the [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil) python library) to see a list of running processes on my linux machine. I want to deterimine which processes are running Go applications (that is, they are running Go code).

Below is the `ps` output for a process that is written in Go. Is there anything that indicates that it is running Go code?

```
{'cmdline': ['./SampleMePlz'],
 'connections': [connection(fd=3, family=10, type=1, laddr=('::', 8080), raddr=(), status='LISTEN')],
 'cpu_affinity': [0, 1, 2, 3],
 'cpu_percent': 0.0,
 'cpu_times': cputimes(user=0.0, system=0.0),
 'create_time': 1436474176.89,
 'cwd': '/home/ben/gocode/src/SampleMePlz',
 'exe': '/home/ben/gocode/src/SampleMePlz/SampleMePlz',
 'ext_memory_info': meminfo(rss=4071424, vms=192684032, shared=3092480, text=3096576, lib=0, data=179523584, dirty=0),
 'gids': group(real=5000, effective=5000, saved=5000),
 'io_counters': io(read_count=12, write_count=0, read_bytes=4096, write_bytes=0),
 'ionice': ionice(ioclass=0, value=4),
 'memory_info': meminfo(rss=4071424, vms=192684032),
 'memory_maps': [mmap(path='/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so', rss=65536, size=2199552, pss=8192, shared_clean=57344, shared_dirty=0, private_clean=0, private_dirty=8192, referenced=65536, anonymous=8192, swap=0),
                 mmap(path='/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so', rss=311296, size=3903488, pss=26624, shared_clean=286720, shared_dirty=0, private_clean=0, private_dirty=24576, referenced=311296, anonymous=24576, swap=0),
                 mmap(path='[stack]', rss=8192, size=139264, pss=8192, shared_clean=0, shared_dirty=0, private_clean=0, private_dirty=8192, referenced=8192, anonymous=8192, swap=0),
                 mmap(path='[anon]', rss=946176, size=179245056, pss=946176, shared_clean=0, shared_dirty=0, private_clean=0, private_dirty=946176, referenced=946176, anonymous=946176, swap=0),
                 mmap(path='/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so', rss=122880, size=151552, pss=13312, shared_clean=110592, shared_dirty=0, private_clean=0, private_dirty=12288, referenced=122880, anonymous=12288, swap=0),
                 mmap(path='[vsyscall]', rss=0, size=4096, pss=0, shared_clean=0, shared_dirty=0, private_clean=0, private_dirty=0, referenced=0, anonymous=0, swap=0),
                 mmap(path='[heap]', rss=4096, size=135168, pss=4096, shared_clean=0, shared_dirty=0, private_clean=0, private_dirty=4096, referenced=4096, anonymous=4096, swap=0),
                 mmap(path='[vdso]', rss=4096, size=4096, pss=0, shared_clean=4096, shared_dirty=0, private_clean=0, private_dirty=0, referenced=4096, anonymous=0, swap=0),
                 mmap(path='/home/ben/gocode/src/SampleMePlz/SampleMePlz', rss=2908160, size=6905856, pss=2908160, shared_clean=0, shared_dirty=0, private_clean=2879488, private_dirty=28672, referenced=2908160, anonymous=28672, swap=0)],
 'memory_percent': 0.025919821179310142,
 'name': 'SampleMePlz',
 'nice': 0,
 'num_ctx_switches': amount(voluntary=15, involuntary=18),
 'num_fds': 5,
 'num_threads': 6,
 'open_files': [],
 'pid': 111252,
 'ppid': 42061,
 'status': 'sleeping',
 'terminal': '/dev/pts/9',
 'threads': [thread(id=111252, user_time=0.0, system_time=0.0),
             thread(id=111253, user_time=0.0, system_time=0.0),
             thread(id=111254, user_time=0.0, system_time=0.0),
             thread(id=113972, user_time=0.0, system_time=0.0),
             thread(id=113973, user_time=0.0, system_time=0.0),
             thread(id=113974, user_time=0.0, system_time=0.0)],
 'uids': user(real=3008, effective=3008, saved=3008),
 'username': 'ben'}
```

Comment: Only as a matter of convention but clearly these things do; 'cwd': '/home/ben/gocode/src/SampleMePlz',
 'exe': '/home/ben/gocode/src/SampleMePlz/SampleMePlz',

Comment: Good point. I'd rather not depend on the directory it is executed from to be  my $GOPATH. It feels a bit hacky (and won't always work).

Comment: Yeah it is a hack. Otherwise I think the answer is no. Which is good because the OS has no business disclosing the implementation details of software it's running anyway. Maybe my IP is obfuscated in that binary.

Comment: What do you mean "my IP"?

Comment: Intellectual Property. Like the OS shouldn't help you to peer into the inner workers of compiled applications.

Comment: He's correct the answer is no. It is a compiled language which means that it is machine code which is running. You could possibly tell by memory fingerprints and run time metrics but that would take a lot more efford and sort of forensic analysis. Unlike Python which runs inside Python so you can see that through ps

Comment: It's probably for categorizing your own procs--in that case a convention like @evanmcdonnal mentioned in the first comment makes lots of sense to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is no. The code is compiled leaving no information about what language/compiler produced it. You can look for symptoms of a go-program, like references to your GOPATH or sub directories of it, but not much more.

Comment: Even such doesn't proof that it is a "go" process, their are symptoms not proof.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @evanmcdonnal's answer, here's a (very, very) hacky solution:

```
strings /path/to/binary/from/ps/output | grep 'runtime.gogc'
```

Output:

```
<snip>
runtime.gogc                                                                                            runtime.gogc   
runtime.gogc   
<snip>
```

This of course relies on the binary format not changing or otherwise being obfuscated, which is not a good assumption to make long-term. I'm also assuming that `runtime.gogc` exists across all Go binaries (it may not).

Note that it would be **very** rare for this to be useful information from an operational point of view.